# Which pong console is this?

Tags: game-consoles

Sorry for the poor quality of the image, I'm trying to recognize the exact model of this console, you can see it on the movie "Stridulum" a.k.a "The visitor" 1978 USA at minute 00:18 and 00:51

[image: the console appear]

[image: the details]

the console is for sure made in USA(the European voltage is different), or is made in other country and the adapted for USA.
Is really similar to those consoles:

1. the Soundic SD-062 TV-18 but is not this because the two controller are different
2. the Tandy TV Scoreboard 60-9005 but is not this because the Tandy has red buttons and those are white
3. the POPPY 9017-Colour TV Game but is not this because the color are different and the Poppy 9017 was sold in Europe
4. the Creatronic Bi.Bip 100 but is not this because was sold in France.

Finally the Italian(but is made in Hong Kong) TELE PARTNER CONSOLE CL 2002 is practically identical(even the color of buttons) but in USA must be had another name, someone know the exact name/model of the pong console in the pictures?

Comment: You're right about the Soundic having joysticks instead of dials, but I've found two different photographs of the same model of Soundic that have different coloured buttons (the four white buttons under the girl's hand) so I wouldn't dismiss the Tandy because of the button colour.

Comment: The movie seems to have been filmed in the US and Italy with Italian writers, directors... Why don't you think it's not the [Giochi Televisivi](https://www.old-computers.com/museum/computer.asp?st=2&c=1192)?

Comment: The directors were Italians but the movie was filmed in USA, as I know in Italy the voltage is 220V in USA is 110V

Comment: As long as the mains frequency doesn't make a mess of things you can always use a simple transformer. Immigrants in the US have used that for ages, as people in other countries used transformers the other way round to use US equipment in other countries.

Comment: Never count out the possibility that it was a non working display unit they showed and any game play was on  another unit.